# Gatekeeper/Knock Knock Pluging not working

Tags: craft3, plugins

I feel like there must be something i've missed but i've followed the ReadMes for both of these plugins and they don't seem to work on my website. Does anyone have any experience with them?

I'm using Craft 3 and used the plugin store to install them. I have tried them one at a time so that they don't interfere with each other. I've also made sure the site environment is set to production.

Gatekeeper:
https://github.com/tomdiggle/craft-gatekeeper/blob/v1/README.md

Knock Knock
https://github.com/verbb/knock-knock

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for Gatekeeper, but I'm a big fan of Knock Knock.

Were you logged out at the time? If you are logged in, it will bypass the security screen.